# What is the correct restful API design when we have optional behavior?

Tags: java, rest, api

I have use case where a class of students is broken down into teams.
class has a classId and team has a teamId.

I have the following options:

1. Create 2 endpoints:

   ```
   @GET
   @Path("/schoolMetadata/byClass/{classId}")
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   public Response getMetadataByClassId(
   ```

and

```
    @GET
    @Path("/schoolMetadata/byTeam/{teamId}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getMetadataByTeamId(
```

2. Second implementation would be using query param.

   ```
   @GET
   @Path("/schoolMetadata/by/")
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   public Response getMetadataById(
       @QueryParam("classId") final Id classId
       @QueryParam("teamId") final Id groupId) {
       if (classid != null) {
       }  else {
       }
   }
   ```

Which of the 2 approaches is better ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea behind RESTful urls is that they should represent 'resources' which are singular or plural nouns. Resources that represent a 'collection' of like things should be plural. You have indicated that school metadata can be obtained for either a class id or a team id. That sound like classes and teams might be considered as 'resources', regardless of whether they are both modeled internally as a 'schoolMetadata'. Without any other information, I might suggest something like:

- **classes/{classId}**
- **teams/{teamId}**

If you're using jaxrs, it would natural to wind up with urls that look something a little more like this:

- **schoolMetadata/resources/classes/{classId}**
- **schoolMetadata/resources/teams/{teamid}**

You might also want to implement:

- **schoolMetadata/resources/classes** to produce a list of 'classes'. Query params could be used here to facilitate search options.
- **schoolMetadata/resources/teams** to produce a list of 'teams' . . .

Comment: Actually, REST says to treat URLs as opaque. There's no such thing as a "RESTful URL". Please don't conflate hackable URL best practices with REST constraints.

Comment: Eric, have you read [Fieldings dissertation](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1). I don't think he agrees with you.

Comment: I have, in fact. Please point out where in the dissertation it suggests that REST URLs should contain semantically meaningful information for the client? I would also refer you to the horse's mouth: https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven

Comment: I've already provided a link to the section which discusses this. It states plainly 'The key abstraction of information in REST is a resource. Any information that can be named can be a resource: a document or image, a temporal service (e.g. "today's weather in Los Angeles"), a collection of other resources, a non-virtual object (e.g. a person), and so on. In other words, any concept that might be the target of an author's hypertext reference must fit within the definition of a resource. A resource is a conceptual mapping to a set of entities...'

Comment: The section you're quoting provides no guidance on what a URL should look like. Neither does anyplace else in the dissertation. REST, as defined by Fielding, means you're using HATEOAS and following links, not hacking URLs. Hackable URLs are a convenience for developers. They may or may not be good design, but they are not REST.

Comment: The section I'm quoting calls the resource identification scheme a 'key abstraction'. Not an opaque meaningless identifier. I agree that clients should be depending on HATEOAS links. That does not imply or require that resource identifiers be opaque, and meaningless.

Comment: No, it doesn't. The *resource* is the key abstraction, not the identification scheme. There is no discussion in the dissertation as to what URLs should look like. Consider https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/evaluation.htm#sec_6_2_4, which discusses not binding semantics to URLs. "At no time whatsoever do the server or client software need to know or understand the meaning of a URI -- they merely act as a conduit through which the creator of a resource (a human naming authority) can associate representations with the semantics identified by the URI."

Comment: Yes, it does - 'Any information that can be named can be a resource' . You may notice that he didn't write "Any information that can be identified by an opaque and meaningless identifier can be a resource'.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the first approach is better because it fits the Single Responsibility Principle (**S**OLID).

> The single responsibility principle (SRP) asserts that a class or module should do one thing only. Now, this is kind of subjective, so the principle is reinforced with the heuristic that the class or module should have only one reason to change.

1 approach has two methods (modules) and each do only one thing